# Event safe invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, interface, thread-safety

Assuming i have this :

```
public event ItemListCharged ListOfItemCharged;

protected virtual void OnItemListCharged(TreeNode t)
{
     ListOfItemCharged?.Invoke(t);
}
```

The OnItemListCharged is used by a Thread, that i will call "ProcessDataThread". The problem is on this class :

```
 public Form1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     formData = new Data(this);
     formData.ListOfItemCharged += displayTree;
 }

 private void displayTree(TreeNode racine)
 {
     liste.Nodes.Add(racine);
 }
```

The displayTree as to be runned by the main thread, the "winforms thread". So i encounter exception everytime because the OnItemCharged event is raised by the ProcessDataThread.

Is there a way to update the liste by raising event without passing on another delegate to invoke it on the winform thread ?

Comment: There's no easy way (you can fiddle around trying to make `async/await` fit the event model, but it's much easier just to use `InvokeRequired()` and `Invoke()` from inside `displayTree()`).

Comment: Some it can only be possible if i work on an async way ?

Comment: No you don't need to use `async` - you just need to use `InvokeRequired()` and `Invoke()` inside `displayTree()`. Do you want me to post an example as an answer? I assumed you already knew about those, and are asking how to do it without using them...

Comment: Sure i know what you mean, but you don't understand what i mean. If i want to pass through this method, i have to work with async/await ?

Comment: You don't need to use async/await...

Comment: You don't understand what i mean. IS it true that if i don't want to use Invoke and InvokeRequired, i have t otake a lokk at async/await ?

Comment: Ah ok, well no you could use something like `RX Extensions` and `Observable.FromEventPattern<T>`.

Comment: Ok fine, will look at this, thanks